# override customer address model in custom module

Tags: php, magento

I want to be a add one custom function in abstract.php which is located in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address`

```
public function getCorrectAddress(){
    $post_data['strret'] = '18334 W. Purdue Ave.';
    $post_data['city'] = 'Waddell';
    $post_data['state'] = 'AZ';
    $post_data['zip'] = '85355';

    //traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
    foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
        $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
    }

    //create the final string to be posted using implode()
    $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

    echo "post string=$post_string";
    echo"<br>";
    //create cURL connection
    $curl_connection = curl_init("http://www.example.com/.urlencode(json_encode($post_string))");

    //set options
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string)
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    //set data to be posted
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

    //perform our request
    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

    //show information regarding the request
    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
    echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . curl_error($curl_connection);

    //close the connection
    curl_close($curl_connection);
    return $result;
}
```

and that result display in edit.phtml page in following textfeilds.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" valign="top">Street</td>
        <td width="2%">:</td>
        <td width="68%"><input name="Street" type="text" id="correctStreet" size="50" </td>
    </tr>           
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">City</td>
        <td valign="top">:</td>
        <td><input name="City" type="text" id="correctCity" size="50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">State</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="State" type="text" id="correctState" size="44"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">Zip</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="Zip" cols="32" rows="4" id="correctZip"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" value="xyz" id="newcity">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="This will real submit the form" />
```

But I am confused about how to do this?  The `getCorrectAddress()` function should get the address from the form when `edit.phtml` is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

this question has been answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19196/4426)

> The best way to implement this is to override the core model.
>   To do that you add a few nodes in your module's config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <address>Your_Module_Model_Customer_Address</address>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

Then you can create a class into your Magento structure:

app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Customer/Address.php

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Customer_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address
{

    public function getCorrectAddress()
    {
        /**
         * Your custom code goes here...
         */
    }

}
```

Thank you

[Tiago Sampaio](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/6338/tiago-sampaio)